# How to save lxrandr settings for next time?

Tags: x11, xrandr, monitors, window-maker

I am running Window Maker. I used lxrandr to set the screen size, and settings for when a second monitor is added. The problem is, after restarting the computer, it reverts to the default settings. How to I save and keep those settings, so they are used whenever I start X?

Comment: For a similar use case I wrote a one-line script and put it in Startup Applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lxrandr` command is best suited to run from the LXDE desktop environment rather than from any arbitrary environment.

It saves its settings in a `.desktop` entry (compliant with [Freedesktop](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/)) there:

```
$HOME/.config/autostart/lxrandr-autostart.desktop
```

which includes this entry:

```
OnlyShowIn=LXDE
```

According to the [Fredesktop specifications](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/0.5/ar01s02.html) that means this will autostart only on LXDE.

- If Window Maker followed these specifications (I think it doesn't), you could try and remove this entry to have it still autostart.
- Else you can just extract the `Exec=` entry and have it autostart the WindowMaker way, by (creating or) editing `~/GNUstep/Library/WindowMaker/autostart` and adding the command above. You'd have to do this manually each time you change a setting with `lxrandr`.
- Or you could instead automate this by adding this in `~/GNUstep/Library/WindowMaker/autostart`:

  ```
  sed -n 's/^Exec=//p' $HOME/.config/autostart/lxrandr-autostart.desktop | sh
  ```

which will execute the *Exec=* entry from the file saved by *lxrandr*.

---

Example of content (`grep ^Exec= $HOME/.config/autostart/lxrandr-autostart.desktop`)

```
Exec=sh -c 'xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60.00 --output eDP1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60.00 --below HDMI1'
```